# Sending a.bmp to a thermal printer

Tags: vb.net, printing

Could someone please point me in the right direction here.
I have an image which is created by a windows form and saved to the filesystem. I want to then send that file to a label printer just after its saved. Everytime I do this the printer just prints rubbish.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

```
    Imports System
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure DOCINFO
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> _
    Public pDocName As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> _
    Public pOutputFile As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> _
    Public pDataType As String
End Structure 'DOCINFO
 _


Public Class PrintDirect
    <DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=False, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Public Shared Function OpenPrinter(ByVal pPrinterName As String, ByRef phPrinter As IntPtr, ByVal pDefault As Integer) As Long

    End Function


    <DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=False, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Public Shared Function StartDocPrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr, ByVal Level As Integer, ByRef pDocInfo As DOCINFO) As Long

    End Function


    <DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Public Shared Function StartPagePrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr) As Long

    End Function


    <DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Public Shared Function WritePrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr, ByVal data As String, ByVal buf As Integer, ByRef pcWritten As Integer) As Long

    End Function




    <DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Public Shared Function EndPagePrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr) As Long

    End Function


    <DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Public Shared Function EndDocPrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr) As Long

    End Function

    <DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Public Shared Function ClosePrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr) As Long

    End Function
End Class 'PrintDirect

Public Class MyPrint
    Public Shared Function SendImageToPrint(ByVal top As Integer, ByVal left As Integer, ByVal image As System.Drawing.Bitmap) As String
        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
        Dim bw As New System.IO.BinaryWriter(ms, Encoding.ASCII)
        Dim dWidth As Double
        dWidth = CType(image.Width / 8, Double)
        Dim P3 As Integer = Math.Ceiling(dWidth)
        Dim strFormat As String = String.Format("GW{0},{1},{2},{3},", top, left, P3, image.Height)
        bw.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strFormat))
        Dim canvasWidth As Integer = P3 * 8
        For y As Integer = 0 To image.Height - 1
            For x As Integer = 0 To canvasWidth - 1
                Dim abyte As Byte = 0
                For b As Integer = 0 To 7
                    x = x + 1
                    If x < image.Width Then
                        Dim dot As Integer = 1
                        Dim color As System.Drawing.Color = image.GetPixel(x, y)
                        Dim luminance As Integer = CType(((color.R * 0.3) + (color.G * 0.59) + (color.B * 0.11)), Integer)
                        If luminance > 127 Then
                            dot = 1
                        Else
                            dot = 0
                        End If

                        abyte = abyte Or CType(dot << (7 - b), Byte)
                    End If
                Next
                bw.Write(abyte)
            Next
        Next
        bw.Write(vbCrLf)
        bw.Flush()
        ms.Position = 0
        Return Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(ms.ToArray())

    End Function

    Public Shared Sub PrintFunction(ByVal barcodeImage As System.Drawing.Image)
        Dim lhPrinter As New System.IntPtr()

        Dim di As New DOCINFO()
        Dim pcWritten As Integer = 0
        Dim st1 As String


        ' text to print with a form feed character  
        ' st1 = strContent
        di.pDocName = "SplitPackManager"
        di.pDataType = "NT EMF 1.008"



        Dim resultStatus As Long = PrintDirect.OpenPrinter("Two Pilots Demo Printer", lhPrinter, 0)
        'Dim resultStatus As Long = PrintDirect.OpenPrinter("LD670 Raster", lhPrinter, 0)

        'MessageBox.Show(resultStatus.ToString)

        PrintDirect.StartDocPrinter(lhPrinter, 1, di)
        PrintDirect.StartPagePrinter(lhPrinter)

        Try

            'PrintDirect.WritePrinter(lhPrinter, st1, st1.Length, pcWritten)
            Dim bitmap As System.Drawing.Bitmap
            bitmap = CType(barcodeImage, System.Drawing.Bitmap)
            Dim strImage = SendImageToPrint(72, 36, bitmap)
            PrintDirect.WritePrinter(lhPrinter, strImage, strImage.Length, pcWritten)
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
            MessageBox.Show("PrintFunction")
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message)
        End Try

        PrintDirect.EndPagePrinter(lhPrinter)
        PrintDirect.EndDocPrinter(lhPrinter)
        PrintDirect.ClosePrinter(lhPrinter)
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried and maybe some steps to recreate the problem

Comment: How do you print? What file format is the file?

Comment: Here is the code I have used...

Comment: Ive added the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to use the PrintDocument class. Here's a rough outline.

```
Dim pd As PrintDocument
AddHandler pd.PrintPage, AddressOf printPage
' assign pd properties
pd.Print

Sub printPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs)
' assign img, set rectangle, determine number of pages, etc.
e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, rectangle)  ' essentially draws on the printer page
e.HasMorePages = ...
end sub
```